# Mottie's Virtual Keyboard keep keyboard after accept action

Tags: jquery

I would like to modify the behavior of accept `keyaction` so that the keyboard does not close after accepting the value

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Actions#defaultaction ?

Comment: Yes, this is the default action : $.keyboard.keyaction = {
  accept : function(base) {
    base.close(true); // same as base.accept();
    return false;     // return false prevents further processing
  } and I am not sure if changing base.close to false is correct

Comment: Try removing the `base.close()` line? :D

Comment: I assign  the accept action to enter key : $.keyboard.keyaction.enter = $.keyboard.keyaction.accept and now I change for this : $.keyboard.keyaction.enter = function(base) {
              return false;
        }; and with this enter do nothing not even the accept

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code as code can be read more easily in the question than in the comments. Use the format as code button or indent the code with four spaces.